# How to import a CSS file in a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relative-path

I want to import a CSS file into a react component.

I've tried `import disabledLink from "../../../public/styles/disabledLink";` but I get the error below;

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../public/styles/disabledLink in c:\Users\User\Documents\pizza-app\client\src\components @ ./client/src/components/ShoppingCartLink.js 19:20-66 Hash: 2d281bb98fe0a961f7c4 Version: webpack 1.13.2

`C:\Users\User\Documents\pizza-app\client\public\styles\disabledLink.css` is the location of the CSS file I'm trying to load.

To me it seems like import is not looking up the correct path.

I thought with `../../../` it would start to look up the path three folder layers above.

`C:\Users\User\Documents\pizza-app\client\src\components\ShoppingCartLink.js` is the location of the file that should import the CSS file.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hey what's up :D, it's looks like only two folder above (components & src)

Comment: Hey, you're right but it still dosn't work. I noticed that i can't use import, because i can't use export within a CSS file

Comment: using this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926493/classname-styles-not-working-in-react/57667815#57667815

Comment: I am getting error -> @media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:640px) {
^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to use [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) when creating bundle with webpack.

Install it:

```
npm install css-loader --save-dev
```

And add it to loaders in your webpack configs:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      // ...
    ]
  }
};
```

After this, you will be able to include css files in js.

Comment: I'm not allowed to import another module into this project. Is their another solution only working with reactjs or native js?

Comment: So i think i have to use something like this: HTMLElement.style

Comment: It looks a little bit ugly. Why aren't you allowed to add changes in bundle building?

Comment: It's a postprocessing for a workship about reactjs and we're told to solve the requirements with the modules included during workship

Comment: Ok, but just wanted to mention that fetching style tags isn't *importing* css files as you've asked in your question. These are 2 different issues.

Comment: It doesn't work for me after adding this module. It shows an npm error.

Comment: What do I use if I'm only using Babel for JSX transpilation to JavaScript? Is there a Babel plugin to load CSS stylesheet files using ES6 module imports, or do I have to update the whole project to use Webpack?

Answer (score 270):

You don't even have to name it if you don't need to:

e.g.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
```

see a complete example here ([Build a JSX Live Compiler as a React Component](https://egghead.io/lessons/build-a-jsx-live-compiler)).

Comment: Doesn't work for me, when I try running mocha with babel register I get...

I:\....css:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { .filter-bg {
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: Or, use react-helmet and inject the css (if its a url) in the <head> tag

Comment: I am importing css files `import ./App.css` but it adds an entry into head. Is it possible to scope the import of App.css to App component only?
I know there stuff like `App.module.css` but I am importing an antd css file for antd component so I can not really change the name of the file.

Comment: this is the problem with create-react-app, it does things people expect vanilla react does, in order for react to build css, depending on what bundler you use you need a css loader or 2

Answer (score 52):

I would suggest using CSS Modules:

**React**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './table.css';

export default class Table extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <div className={styles.table}>
            <div className={styles.row}>
                <div className={styles.cell}>A0</div>
                <div className={styles.cell}>B0</div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

**Rendering the Component:**

```
<div class="table__table___32osj">
    <div class="table__row___2w27N">
        <div class="table__cell___2w27N">A0</div>
        <div class="table__cell___1oVw5">B0</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would add part 1 as the answer below. And you can follow my answer to test your component.

Comment: If tried this out and it dosn't works. I've tried to include it like this: `import styles from "./disabledLink.css";` and get the following error: Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./disabledLink.css in c:\Users\Basti Kluth\Documents\pizza-app\client\src\components
 @ ./client/src/components/ShoppingCartLink.js 19:20-49

Comment: css modules should be installed apart, https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

Comment: And how can I write media query for such type CSS, any Idea?

Comment: css modules is a different thing and has a different syntax. please don't confuse people.

Answer (score 28):

The following imports an external CSS file in a React component and outputs the CSS rules in the `<head />` of the website.

1. Install [Style Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) and [CSS Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader):

```
npm install --save-dev style-loader
npm install --save-dev css-loader
```

2. In webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

3. In a component file:

```
import './path/to/file.css';
```

Comment: And I use babel to run watcher. Maybe it doesn't see into the webpack.config.js file at all

Comment: Have you installed css-loader? Also I don't see your webpack.config.js.

Comment: You can add more module rules in object format as `rules` array's value.

Answer (score 7):

The solutions above are completely changed and deprecated. If you want to use CSS modules (assuming you imported css-loaders) and I have been trying to find an answer for this for such a long time and finally did. The default webpack loader is quite different in the new version.

In your webpack, you need to find a part starting with cssRegex and replace it with this;

```
{
  test: cssRegex,
  exclude: cssModuleRegex,
  use: getStyleLoaders({
      importLoaders: 1,
      modules: true,
      localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
  }),
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572200/react-css-class-name-import-not-working

Alternate solution

Answer (score 4):

You can import css file if css file reside in a same folder where you want to import than just simple try this

import './styles.css'

if css file is far away from our component that navigate that place where file is reside and use this like

import '../mainstyles/styles.css'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Style Loader and CSS Loader:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev style-loader
   npm install --save-dev css-loader
   ```
2. Configure webpack

   ```
   module: {
           loaders: [
               {
                   test: /\.css$/,
                   loader: 'style-loader'
               }, {
                   test: /\.css$/,
                   loader: 'css-loader',
                   query: {
                       modules: true,
                       localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                   }
               }
           ]
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In cases where you just want to inject some styles from a stylesheet into a component without bundling in the whole stylesheet I recommend https://github.com/glortho/styled-import. For example:

```
const btnStyle = styledImport.react('../App.css', '.button')

// btnStyle is now { color: 'blue' } or whatever other rules you have in `.button`.
```

NOTE: I am the author of this lib, and I built it for cases where mass imports of styles and CSS modules are not the best or most viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the required module.

```
require('./componentName.css');
const React = require('react');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin and css-loader loader work for me, see below:

**webpack.config.js Import extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin**

```
const ExtractCssChunks = require('extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin');
```

**webpack.config.js *Add the css rule*,
Extract css Chunks first then the css loader css-loader will embed them into
the html document, ensure css-loader and extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin are in the package.json dev dependencies**

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: ExtractCssChunks.loader,
          },
          'css-loader',
        ],
      }
]
```

**webpack.config.js Make instance of the plugin**

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractCssChunks({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css'
    })
  ]
```

**And now importing css is possible**
And now in a tsx file like index.tsx i can use import like this
import './Tree.css' where Tree.css contains css rules like

```
body {
    background: red;
}
```

My app is using typescript and this works for me, check my repo for the source :
https://github.com/nickjohngray/staticbackeditor

Answer (score -3):

You can import your `.css` file in `.jsx` file

Here is an example -

```
import Content from '../content/content.jsx';
```