# ClassName styles not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I'm having a little issue with styling react components. I have my scss stylesheets in a separate file and importing them into my react file. My scss stylsheet looks like this:

```
.testStyle {
  font-family: avenir;
  color: blue;
}
```

My react file, looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'

import styles from '../styles/main.scss'

class Temp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      **<div className={styles.testStyle}>**
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Temp
```

With this setup, my styles are not passed through, however, if it works if I replace the starred line with `<div className='testStyle'>`, so it seems like the styles are being imported correctly. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

Comment: hows your webpack config looking? ave you added sass-loader,style-loader,  If in dev mode have you included generated css file into your html?

Answer (score 17):

I assume you are using css loader in your webpack.
You need to enable modules:true

```
{
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: { 
    modules: true
  }
}
```

If you don't want this behaviour to be default, in your (s)css you can use:

```
// sCSS
:local .yourClass {...}

// JS

import cls from '../yourCss.scss'

const Component = () => (
  <div className={cls.yourClass} />
)

// yourClass will become some random hash
// or something else based on your css loader config
```

to have it processed. If you have modules: true and you don't want css loader to compile your class, you can use

```
// CSS
:global .yourGlobalClass {...}

// JS
import '../yourCss.scss'

const Component = () => (
  <div className="yourGlobalClass" />
)
```

See the documentation: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader and https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

Answer (score 9):

Try to **rename the `.scss` filename extension to `.module.scss`**

If there's a problem in the `sass-loader` or you didn't configure it to support `.scss` files - it's original `scss` format will support only the `.module.scss` extension.

I had the same problem and it fixed my issue.

You can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57843706/using-sass-loader-wont-import-classes-dynamically-in-react) the question I've asked of it.

Comment: Was my problem, ty!

Comment: <div  className={style['game']}>
this si not working  and scss is working fine .. can u help me

Answer (score 4):

**Some of Steps will Solve your Problem**

1. The Name Of File Must Be  :  **FileName.module.css**

[image]

### [image]

2. Import File in **App.js**

[image]

3. Used it in **Component**

[image]

4. Browser

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Importing a stylesheet will simply tell Webpack or other build tools to process that stylesheet and include it in the output files. It does not, as far as I know, allow you to template JSX with it. So just by importing it your styles will be available after a build cycle takes place. You don't need to actually use it in any way.

`className` takes a string and directly translates to html `class` - so use it like that.

Comment: I am using webpack style and css loaders so it should allow me to require/import my styles straight into my jsx and handle the build steps.

Comment: hi @pmmoks - i have the same problem, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

```
/* loginScreen.js */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './styles.css'

class loginScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={ 'form' }>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default loginScreen;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have the *sass-loader* missing in your webpack configuration. For that please [check here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx),

My recommendation is to drop *sass* and use *postcss*, it's extensive and works the way your are using classes in your code above.

For a postcss install and config [check here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/postcss-loader/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
import * as styles from '../styles/main.scss'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add some explanation on how this answer fixed the problem and how its different from the other answers (and most important the accepted answer).