# Using sass-loader won't import classes dynamically in React

Tags: css, reactjs, import, sass

My goal is to import `scss-classes` using dynamic classes.

I've seem several usages such as in [Ambar opensource](https://github.com/RD17/ambar/blob/master/FrontEnd/src/components/BasicComponents/FileAvatar/FileAvatar.js), and wish to do something similar in my project.

```
// App.js
import classes from './App.scss'
...
<div className={classes.App}/>
```

```
// App.scss
.App {
  text-align: center;
}
```

- The Problem is that those `css` changes won't occur, using `dev-tools` I can see that none of the classes are a part of the HTML.
- Changing the `className='App'`, will work.
- I've used the command `npm install node-sass -S` for the `SCSS` installation process.

I've found module called [`sass-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader) that handle the request, but after completing the steps on their guide - it still won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This structure is called *CSS Modules*. If you use `create-react-app`, apply these steps.

1) First install `node-sass` module.

```
npm install node-sass
```

2) Save your `SCSS` file with `.module.scss` **extension**. For example:

```
App.module.scss
```

3) Import this file like this:

```
import classes from "./App.module.scss";
```

4) Now, you can apply your styles like this:

```
<div className={classes.App}>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks ! 
However, Is there any way to resolve it without changing the `scss` file-extensions? 
On the project `Ambar` (link above) it seems that they just called their `scss` files with a simple `.scss` extension.

Comment: As far as I know you have to add `.module.scss` extension. This is how `CSS Modules` works. @YanivGK

Comment: I think that it's related to the `webpack.config.js` settings. There's a regex related to the `css extension`, and it's mentioned on the documentation of `sass-loader`.
Because I'm using the `react-scripts` to manage the setup and not `webpack`'s - I've decided to use the `module.scss` solution. So I'll resolve the question - Thanks again.