# How to show the border css over the div element?

Tags: html, css

[Image attached in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V5O0.png)

**In number 9 cell border is over the background color**

How do I show the border over the div or background Color and it should be responsive?

```
<div className="borderOverDiv"><div>
<div className="backgroundClr"></div>

.borderOverDiv{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: calc(100% - 94%);
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.backgroundClr{
    background: blue
}
```

this code as I tried, seems not working

Comment: Please share your code..

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Save people the hassle of writing out and/or guessing what your html and css are, if they want to experiment with the problem.

Comment: I may be wrong but i think that it is done with pseudolement that hovers above said div and create this effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are new to css so I will try to explain what is going on with this code the best that i can.

The fun part is in `.element.active:after`
There is a few thing

1. `position: absolute` this will allow us to set this element absolutly to container. But witch container? First that has `position` set to a different value than `static` or its initial value. That is why `.element` has `position: relative` which doesn't do anything on its own.
2. `top, right, bottom, left` which tell that this element will be exceeding parent element on every side by `5px`.
3. `z-index` Simply the higher the value the "closer" this element is to user. initial value is `0` so `1` is placing this element above every other element.
4. `content` is required in [pseudo-element :after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) in order to show them. This property just needs to be set and doesn't have to have any value specified.

The reis is just to make it look nicer.
And thats it.

You can use other element inside `.element` if you feel like it.

For example

```html
<div class="element">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

and it will work just fine if you will follow point form 1 to 3 (point 4 is required, as I said earlier, only in pseudo-element) but it will be less responsive. For example what will you have to do when other element needs this overlay? You will have to use javascript to append `.overlay` element to `.element` and with pseudo-element you just need to append class. or just show this overlay on `hover`. Other advantage is that it look prettier and doesn't bloat you html.

```css
.container {
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
}

.element {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0000ff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.element.active:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, .4);
    border: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200 ,.8);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">7</div>
    <div class="element active">8</div>
    <div class="element">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @ciekals its almost working, one more thing how to show the border only when I hover?

Comment: you can change `.element.active:after` to `.element:hover:after` and this pseudo-element will show only on hover

Comment: thanks, it's working as expected, I close this issue

Answer (score -1):

replacing **className** with **class** should do the trick

Comment: using reactjs library, so className only will work

Comment: ohh. .. you should've added that in the tags.. haven't worked with reactjs so i don't have any idea.

Comment: @ranjithvbr 
maybe this might help you 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926493/classname-styles-not-working-in-react#:~:text=Try%20to%20rename%20the%20.scss,scss%20extension)

Comment: able to see the CSS property that I applied in code, but it's not as per the image