# Using Morris.js with reactjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, morris.js

How can I use reactjs to create a morris.js chart?
I am using an Asp.net MVC5 project with react.js library. It is my first react project, and I want to change a morris.js chart when some button clicked.
I don't want to use other react library just morris js librayr inside react js script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can make Morris.js work with React.

1. Install Morris.js and its dependency - Raphael.js:

```
npm install --save-dev morris.js
npm install --save-dev raphael
```

2. In your component:

```
import Raphael from 'raphael';
import 'morris.js/morris.css';
import 'morris.js/morris.js';
```

3. Morris looks for Raphael to be in global scope

```
constructor() {
    super();
    window.Raphael = Raphael;
}
```

## Important notes

1. If you get a compilation error for `morris.css`, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49359522/776687).
2. If you write `import Morris from 'morris.js/morris.js'`, it won't work.
3. There's another way to make Raphael be in global scope.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            Raphael: 'raphael'
        })
    ],
    ...
}
```

If you prefer this variant, you don't need:

```
import Raphael from 'raphael';
window.Raphael = Raphael;
```

Comment: tried this solution but I get a "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined", i don't know why. I have installed jQuery because I also have boostrap.

Comment: I would make sure jQuery is called before Raphael and Morris scripts.

Comment: Done. But after trying to use it like in the answer provided by @novasaint, I got an error

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

In `componentDidMount()` draw your chart, in my example it's a donut:

`yourChart = Morris.Donut({
  element: 'elementId',
  data: data,
  // ...other options
});`

where `yourChart` is declared outside of the class or you can do `this.yourChart` in the `constructor()`.

If you want to update/redraw your chart, you can call `yourChart.setData(newData)` at the button click.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I found this framework on internet: http://recharts.org/                                                                                         and it worked well for me

Comment: Now I get a `TypeError: morris_js_morris_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a.Area is not a function`