# Reactjs - Importing CSS/JS in component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, requirejs

I am trying to create a webpage using a HTML theme on [Reactjs](https://reactjs.org/). I have studied and found there are 4 ways to import CSS at [this link](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822). All these ways outputs the same way i.e `<style>MY_CSS</style>` just before closing HEAD tag.

This is OK for single CSS but when we are using multiple CSS it may conflict with other one.

So my question is can we import CSS so that it will show in  not as `<style></style>`. As `<style>` tags works as inline CSS and I don't want to use it inline.

2nd question: How can I import Js?
As I am using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) to load multiple js, for this I am trying to import `require.config.js` where my other js are called.

Please have a look what I am getting
[image: this is I am getting from all the codes I have used]

Need to have like this below
[image: I need CSS to import it like this but not commented, this is a commented code]

Please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to learn `React` and the way you should structure a `React` project ( this includes everything, from `css`, to multiple `js` files, etc ) is to use [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

Let me try to elaborate a bit.

`React` is a javascript library. You could, for example, get the library from a `cdn` and include it in your `index.html` file much in the same way you would get `jquery` for example. And, with the library included, you could do things like this:

```
const element = React.createElement(
  'h1',
  null,
  'Hello, world!'
);
const container = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(element, container);
```

Since you have the library from a `cdn`, you have access to it's methods, for example `createElement` and the library will look for a node in the `dom` with `id` called `root` and insert there a `h1` node containing `Hello, world!`. You could then apply to the newly created node a style of your choice.

This example was taken from [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?presets=react&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBApgGzgWzmWBeGAeAFgRgD4AJRBEAGhgHcQAnBAEwEJsB6AwgbgChRJY_KAEMAlmDh0YWRiGABXVOgB0AczhQAokiVQAQgE8AkowAUAcjogQUcwEpeAJTjDgUACIB5ALLK6aRklTRBQ0KCohMQk6Bx4gA)

While it is certainly possible to use `React` this way, you shouldn't, in my opinion.

What you should do is follow the steps outlined in the `create-react-app` link and bootstrap a project using `create-react-app`. This will give you a pre configured project, that will allow you to use the library in a modern way.

The project that `create-react-app` offers you is set up to use a tool called [`webpack`](https://webpack.js.org/) and a tool called [`babel`](https://babeljs.io/). `Webpack` is a `module bundler`. Using a set of rules, it will take several files and bundle them together. How and why it works is beyond the scope of this question. `Babel` is a javascript compiler or syntax transformer. Also using a set of rules, it turns [`ES6`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2015) into regular javascript. Again, the how and the way are out of scope. What you should know is, because of `webpack` and `babel`, you will be able to write code like this.

`import styles from 'style.module.css'`

This is done with no effort on your part, because everything is already configured by `create-react-app`.

This is why I recommend you start with this. Just install it, bootstrap a project and take a quick look at how `App.js` is set up. You will see there `css` imports, `component` imports and will give you a good if shallow overview of how a modern `React` project works.

Answer (score 1):

This is just done via ordinary ES. For example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './SomeFileWithStyle.css'
```

The second line imports a CSS file containing, well, CSS code. You are now able to use the classes specified in there. Follow this guide if you need further help: [Styling and CSS - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html).

Read more about the ES import statement here: [import - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: Yes it will import CSS in <style> just before closing head tag but I want to use it as <link> tag

Answer (score 1):

Import your .css file from the correct path. I struggled with using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`
 in index.html without any luck. 
But instead:

**index.html**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/style.css"/>
```

**style.css**:

```
div.custom-div {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Now, you can use

```
<div className="custom-div">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css-loader when creating bundle with wepback.

Install it:

`npm install css-loader --save-dev`

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39853767/9740125)