# Can't apply css to React className

Tags: css, reactjs, components, classname

Can't apply css to React className...

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";

class CompanyInfo extends React.Component {

render() {

    return (
        <div className="CompanyInfo">
            <ul>
                <li className="Name">Company Name</li>
                <li className="Production">Production</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};
}

export default CompanyInfo;
```

here's my CSS

```
.CompanyInfo {
list-style: none;
font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
color: white;
}

.Name {
font-size: 20px;
}

.Production {
font-size: 16px;
}
```

but this doesn't work! it still appears like a list

[The image to see how it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH7q4.png)

without any CSS :/

Can you help me? :)

Comment: how your react project is configured?

Comment: @SergChernata what do you mean? In React `className` is used to add class attributes. Because `class` is a reserved keyword in JS.

Comment: Try setting up a css loader as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853646/how-to-import-a-css-file-in-a-react-component

Comment: @AnaFig do you get any 404 any console?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I configured with webpack and babel. 
and I didn't get any 404 on my console, what is weird

Comment: show your webpack config then.. do you have the loaders configured.. ?

Comment: @AnaFig you got the answer. your css rule was wrong..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works now! :)

```
//Changed this  
import "./index.css" 
//To this
import Styles from "./index.css"


//Change this
<li className="Name">Company Name</li>
//To this
<li className={Styles.Name}>Company Name</li>
```

Thanks to all of you who helped me in seconds!!!

Answer (score 3):

You have the css style `list-style: none;` so I think `CompanyInfo` class should be applied to the `ul` element instead of the `div`, it should probably be

```
return (
    <div>
        <ul className="CompanyInfo">
            <li className="Name">Company Name</li>
            <li className="Production">Production</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
);
```

or maybe

```
return (
    <ul className="CompanyInfo">
        <li className="Name">Company Name</li>
        <li className="Production">Production</li>
    </ul>
);
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! :)
still doesn't work, but that part at least I changed for better

Comment: @AnaFig Just to debug.. add body { background: red} in the css file and what do you see now?

Comment: I suspect your css is not loaded correctly, do you use `webpack` ? Did you declare the `css-loader` and the `style-loader` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853646/how-to-import-a-css-file-in-a-react-component

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised you had to make this changes for it to work

```
//Changed this  
import "./index.css" 
//To this
import Styles from "./index.css"


//Change this
<li className="Name">Company Name</li>
//To this
<li className={Styles.Name}>Company Name</li>
```

Your first implementation like so

```
import "./index.css" 


<li className="Name">Company Name</li>
```

should work well also. 
I implemented something similar  for my own project like so and it works well.

```
import React from "react";
import "../index.css";

export default function Header() {
  return <header className="navbar">This is my header</header>;
}
```

my `index.css` file

```
.navbar {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: purple;
  color: whitesmoke;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```