# Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:0) when adding css to .css file

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-router

I have added the following code to a .css file which is linked to a React component.

```
.navbar-brand {
color: #333;
}

a {
color: #333;
font-weight: 200;
}
```

These are the import statements in my .jsx file:

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Navbar.css';


class Navbar extends Component {
render() {
    return (

        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md">
            <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div className="container">

            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item active">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/">Link</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link>
                </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </nav>


    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Does this have something to do with the path of the .css file?  Any help would be appreciated.
This is the error it is giving me in the console.

```
ERROR in ./src/components/Navbar.css
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:0)

 8 |     font-weight: 200;
 9 | } */
 > 10 | .navbar-brand {
 | ^
 11 |     color: #333;
 12 | }
```

Comment: could you post the whole css file?

Comment: That is the whole css file. I think it might be that there is no Navarro-brand in my html and no a tags.

Comment: I mean navbar-brand .

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference, did you make the app with `create-react-app`?

Comment: No I  didn’t. Would that make a difference?

Comment: If you're bundling through `webpack`, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39853767/9782979)

Comment: Ok will try that. Or alternatively shall I build it again using create-react-app .

Comment: yeah `create-react-app` is really useful in that it abstracts all the nitty gritty of building the project away :)

Comment: I might do that instead. Thanks for your help Izb

Comment: no problem! good luck