# React : CSS class name import not working

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment

i have a `<main>` div in my react component and im importing some class name from a class css file, but the class name is not getting integrated to the main div when i try to inspect it in the browser. when i simply use other class names its working like `<main className="test">` but importing classes is not working.

This is my component :

```
import React from 'react';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';
import classes from './Layout.css';

const layout = (props) => (
<Aux>
    <div>
        Test paragraph
    </div>
    <main className={classes.Content}>
        {props.children}

    </main>
</Aux>
);

export default layout;
```

This is my css

```
.Content{
   color: red;
   margin-top: 20px;
}
```

I did `npm run eject` command after creation, if there is something to do with the webpack configuration file please help me
( i haven't made any changes there after eject command )

Here is the css part of webpack dev config file

```
{
        test: cssRegex,
        exclude: cssModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders({
          importLoaders: 1,
        }),
      },
      // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
      // using the extension .module.css
      {
        test: cssModuleRegex,
        use: getStyleLoaders({
          importLoaders: 1,
          modules: true,
          getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
        }),
 },
```

Answer (score 19):

`import './Layout.css';`

Then use it like a normal CSS

`<main className="Content">`

You can also use your classes as objects with this format:

**In your CSS file:**
Wrap your classes and id's with `:local(.className)`

***Example***
`:local(.Content) { width: 100px; }`

**In your React Component:**
`import classes from './stylesheet.css'`

`<div className={classes.Content}></div>`

Comment: wow!! it works thanks man.I thought that i still had to use it with props.

Comment: Glad I could help. As a heads up, there's a case-sensitivity issue when switching from development to production. It's the source of a huge frustration unless you know what you're looking for.

Comment: Just be carefull because when you import css file this way, your css classes become global. So take care if you will want to use class named `Content` anywhere else in the code because it will apply styles from this class.

Comment: Coming back to this question : i cant use this syntax :  <main className={classes.Content}> for properly taking classes from css files , i need to do it this way , how do i do that ?is there something that i have to do with the " npm eject " thing ?

Comment: Do you have the two packages suggested by sebinq ?

Comment: https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822

#3 is what you're looking for. It's the same thing sebinq was saying

Comment: I still cant cant use my classes as  <main className={classes.Content}> , i did include the loader configuration thing in my wbpack config file still no use.

Comment: Check my new answer. No need for anything special except a slight change in your css file

Comment: Use this method for global css and the new answer for component specific css

Answer (score 6):

Actually I've used it like this:

```
import classes from './Layout.module.css';
```

As you see in the text of your question:

> // using the extension .module.css

Comment: Right answer. In new versions it works if You use "module.css" extension instead of ".css"

Answer (score 5):

You have to configure some staff. follow these steps:

1. `npm run eject` run this command inside your project root directory
2. search `cssRegex` and add the following lines under   `use: getStyleLoaders({`

   ```
       modules:true,
       localIdentName:'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
   ```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure 'npm run eject' run successfully then you can access webpack.config.js file in config folder.

1. Stop the server.
2. Go to webpack.config.js
3. Find  cssRegex and update as given in the image
   [image: webpack.config.js]
4. Restart the server

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Windows, don't name file 'Aux' it's reserved name.

Solution is just to name your CSS files as (in your case) `Layout.module.css` and then import them as such.

You don't need to eject as from the [Create React App 2.0](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html) since it uses CSS Modules out of the box.

Comment: Spot on. :-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to specify the file's extension like `import classes from './layout.css';`?

Try to instal `style-loader` and `css-loader` packages. Then add to you webpack this:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loaders: [
        'style-loader?sourceMap',
        'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
    ]
}
```

I got if from [css-modules documentation](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules) and I hope it will help you to achieve what you need.

Comment: Did you at least try? It is really not that smart. For example when you are importing svg file you need to specify file extension.

Comment: I tried including extension but still not working "import classes from './Layout.css'; "

Comment: i used create-react-app for making the folder structure and use npm run eject so arent they ( style-loader and css-loader installed and configured out of the box ), or should i include this again to config file ?

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me, if you're using a react version with react-scripts@2.0.0 and higher, they probably wouldn't work for you either.

you must used the CSS Modules alongside regular stylesheets using the [name].module.css file naming convention. CSS Modules allows the scoping of CSS by automatically creating a unique classname of the format [filename]_[classname]__[hash].

example Header.module.css
nb: header here can be any name

Answer (score 0):

To use class names like an object you need to do 2 things:

1. Write import like `import * as classes from './Layout.css';`
2. Include typings defenition for your style.

Example for Typescript - create **Layout.css.d.ts** file with `export const Content: string;`

Be sure that you define `camelCase` option for `css-loader` to resolve dash-classes into camel-case properties that you define in **Layout.css.d.ts**.

Answer (score 0):

I was also working on a react  tutorial and faced same issue.

I updated my webpack.config.js file at line 420 and it was working  for me then. Please try it out.

[image]

line 420:

- localIdentName:'[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]',

Answer (score 0):

For latest version no need to set

localIdentName: '[name]**[local]**[hash:base64:5]',  // no need set any where

Just give your css name with postfix like **FileName.module.css**  ex Personal.module.css

Then class name like below ***filename_classname_randomstring***

**Personal_Person__3L9tz**

it working for me

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
{
          test: cssRegex,
          exclude: cssModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders({
            importLoaders: 1,
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
          modules: {
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

the other answers not worked for me
so I used this solution and worked fine

1: run the `npm run eject` command

2: go to `config/webpack.config.js` and search for `cssRegex`

3: use this code in that particular section

```
test: cssRegex,
exclude: cssModuleRegex,
use: getStyleLoaders({
  importLoaders: 1,
  modules:{
    localIdentName:'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
  },
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below configuration to config/webpack.config.js after running npm run eject in the command line in the project folder and select yes when propted

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed many reference to `test: cssRegex` block, though you may not have it in the webpack config.
If the above is your case try to open webpack.config.dev.js and find block starting with test: `/\.css$/`, (row 160 in my case). Then add the following lines so final result looks like this:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      require.resolve('style-loader'),
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
      },
   },
```

This should enable css modules to work.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution:

## `yarn run eject`

Go to the config/webpack.config.js

Update the file as the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD9lI.png).

```js
            // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
            // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
            // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
            // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
            // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
            // of CSS.
            // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: true,
                localIdentName:'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
              }),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
            // using the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: true,
                getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent
              }),
            },
```