# Importing css file to specific component react app

Tags: css, reactjs, import

I am trying to import css to my specific component of react app.

webpack config:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: 'css-loader',
    }),
}
```

but css is not applied.

I also included the main css inside `index.html`. Is it the reason why I cannot apply another css file?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css">
```

Can you suggest me what's missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572200/react-css-class-name-import-not-working/

Comment: I think @sebinq might have answered your question as it relates to loading css specific to the component. If you don't care about it being specific to the component, my answer in that question should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the `webpack` version you're using. For example, if you're using Webpack 4, then your `development` config would be:

```
{
  test: /\.s?css$/, // test for scss or css files 
  use: [
    'style-loader', // try to use style-loader or...
    {
      loader: 'css-loader', // try to use css-loader 
      options: {
        sourceMap: true, // allow source maps (allows css debugging)
        modules: true, // allow css module imports
        camelCase: true, // allow camel case imports
        localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]', // set imported classNames with a original className and a hashed string in the DOM, for example: "exampleClassName__2fMQK"
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

**example.css** (must use camel case instead of snake case)

```
.exampleClassName {
   text-align: center;
}
```

**example.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { exampleClassName } from './example.css';

export default () => (
  <h1 className={exampleClassName}>I am centered!</h1>
)
```

---

For production, you'll want to use `OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin` and `MiniCssExtractPlugin` :

```
minimizer: [
  new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({ 
    cssProcessorOptions: { 
      map: { 
        inline: false, 
        annotation: true 
      } 
    } 
  }),
],
{
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: `css/[name].[contenthash:8].css`,
        chunkFilename: `[id].[contenthash:8].css`,
    }), 
  ]
}
```

When you run `webpack` to build your application for production, it'll compile the `css` and (when the webpack config is set up properly) will generate an `index.html` that automatically adds a `link` to the compiled stylesheet.

Webpack is a steep learning curve and there's a lot of missing options from the above examples, so if you're just trying to get it up and running, then I have a [Webpack-React-Boilerplate](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/Webpack-React-Boilerplate) that has (s)css modules imports and a lot more already configured for you. I've included notes within the webpack config files to help assist as to what each option is doing.

Otherwise, if you're trying to learn older versions of webpack, then you can eject the create-react-app and reverse engineer/look at their extensive webpack notes.