# React not applying className style to button

Tags: reactjs

I am starting out on React and am just trying to style a button. It is ignoring the styling though. I am not sure if I am missing a package or if I am doing something rather simple incorrectly.

My App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import Transactions from './Components/Transactions';

const App = props => {
  return (
  <div><Transactions /></div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My Transactions.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '../button/button';

const Transactions = (props) => {
    return (
        <Button caption='blah'></Button>
    );
};

export default Transactions;
```

My button.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './button.css';


const button = (props) => (
    <button
        className={classes.Button}>{props.caption}
    </button>
);

export default button;
```

My button.css file (both button.js and button.css are in a button folder under src)

```
.Button {
    font-size: 24pt;
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

**Edit 1**
While I can get this to work by doing just the following modifications in the button.js file, I seek to do the CSS modules approach. I used create-react-app to create the application but think I must be missing something else. Do I need to eject the application? Am I missing an import library?

```
import React from 'react';
import './button.css';


const button = (props) => (
    <button
        className={"Button"}>{props.caption}
    </button>
);

export default button;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a css file in a react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853646/how-to-import-a-css-file-in-a-react-component)

Comment: just set `className="Button"` and `import ./button.css`

Comment: @Rikin - I am not getting errors and if I attempt to debug the page and manually add the class (i.e. via the F12 command in Chrome) it will work.

Comment: @George - className="Button" will not work as it has to come from classes.Button since that was the name it was imported as. The sample shows the import of the css

Comment: Console.log classes and see what you are getting

Comment: If I had just done the import as: import './button.css'; and then done className=<{"Button"}> the example would have worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's on your import and filename. CSS modules follow `{component}.module.css` naming convention. So, you could try:

1. Renaming `button.css` to `button.module.css`
2. `import styles from './button.module.css`
3. Use `styles.Button` in your class name

See: [CSS Modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

Comment: I went back through my React class and followed some of the links and just found that. Your answer is perfect.