# Cannot import css files says error unexpected token

Tags: reactjs

My reactjs application is running successfully.

now I need to import css file**(style.css)**

when I run the code after adding `import "./styles.css";` it displays error **unexpected token**.

```
import {initializeBlock, Input, useBase, useRecords} from '@airtable/blocks/ui';
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import "./styles.css";

class Access extends React.Component {

//content goes here

}
```

I have followed solutions here suggested by **Webars** [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853646/how-to-import-a-css-file-in-a-react-component)  and I have installed **webpack, style-loader, and css-loader**
as per **Mr. Webars** suggestion but the error of **unexpected token** persist when i try to import the css files.

**here is my webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**here is my package.json**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@airtable/blocks": "0.0.51",
        "react": "^16.13.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
        "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.3",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.0",
        "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
        "webpack": "^4.43.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "eslint frontend"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your css file? May be you use any pre processor syntax there?
Or you can remove its content and check if error is still there?

Comment: If I remove the content of css file, the error will be gone. here is example of css  file 
`.centerloader{
background:#D5D5D5;
position:absolute;
color:black;
top:50%;
left:50%;
width:80%;
}`

Comment: Can you provide full error message? Do you have images links (backgrounds or etc.) in your css files?