# Why CSS file is not loaded in the react app

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am building a very simple react app. Everything works fine except the CSS file is not loaded, where is the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/animal_fun_facts/src/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/animal_fun_facts/src/index.js"></script>
    <script src="/app.compiled.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the file structure:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a CSS file in a React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853646/how-to-import-a-css-file-in-a-react-component)

Comment: Static assets you need to put into public folder, if you are going to reference it that way. Otherwise as the other comment suggested you need to import it into a component.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanHatem importing resolved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use so many ways actually
Like css modules,

Since you have created your stylesheet In a separate file, then let's just import it in your application
Use the following :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './animal_fun_facts/src/styles.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your CSS is in the same folder as your HTML file, change your CSS href location to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/index.js"></script>
    <script src="/app.compiled.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Note: Ideally, all your HTML files should be placed in the public folder)

If you are using Visual Code, as you press the backslash key, a list of files in the current folder will be shown so you can locate your css or js files easily.